# Enable multiple many to many in Entity Framework 5 code first to same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I am using Version 5 code first.

I have a model:

```
class RebateBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public RebateType RebateType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TurnoverClassification> AvailableTurnoverClassifications { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TurnoverClassification> EnabledTurnoverClassifications { get; set; }


    public RebateBase()
    {
        if (AvailableTurnoverClassifications == null)
        {
            AvailableTurnoverClassifications = new List<TurnoverClassification>();
        }

        if (EnabledTurnoverClassifications == null)
        {
            EnabledTurnoverClassifications = new List<TurnoverClassification>();
        }

        if (Customers == null)
        {
            Customers = new List<Customer>();
        }
    }
```

and a model

```
class TurnoverClassification
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RebateBase> RebateBases{ get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int NumericalValue { get; set; }
}
```

I already tried to initialize data with and without

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();


        modelBuilder.Entity<RebateBase>()
            .HasMany<TurnoverClassification>(rb => rb.AvailableTurnoverClassifications)
            .WithMany(tc => tc.RebateBases)
            .Map(rt =>
                {
                    rt.MapLeftKey("RebateID");
                    rt.MapRightKey("TurnoverID");
                    rt.ToTable("RebateBase_AvailableTurnoverClassifications");
                });

        modelBuilder.Entity<RebateBase>()
            .HasMany<TurnoverClassification>(rb => rb.EnabledTurnoverClassifications)
            .WithMany(tc => tc.RebateBases)
            .Map(rt =>
            {
                rt.MapLeftKey("RebateID");
                rt.MapRightKey("TurnoverID");
                rt.ToTable("RebateBase_EnabledTurnoverClassifications");
            });
```

But it doesn't work. With the upper approach I get the error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (9,6) : error 0040: Type
>   RebateBase_AvailableTurnoverClassifications is not defined in
>   namespace CustomerConfiguration.Datalayer (Alias=Self).

When I remove the second navigation property enabledturnoverClassifications everythings is fine and I don't need to adapt the mapping in modelbuilder. As soon as I add the second navigationproperty I get the error.

Could anybody please help?

Thank you.

Greetz

Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `InverseProperty` attribute to specify the corresponding collection in the `TurnoverClassification` class to enable multiple many to many relationships. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437366/entity-framework-4-3-code-first-multiple-many-to-many-using-the-same-tables) contains an example of multiple many to many relationships in EF.

I tested this with a Enable-Migrations specified and the correct relation tables were created.

```
class RebateBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public RebateType RebateType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("RebateBasesAvailable")]
    public virtual ICollection<TurnoverClassification> AvailableTurnoverClassifications { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("RebateBasesEnabled")]
    public virtual ICollection<TurnoverClassification> EnabledTurnoverClassifications { get; set; }


    public RebateBase()
    {
        if (AvailableTurnoverClassifications == null)
        {
            AvailableTurnoverClassifications = new List<TurnoverClassification>();
        }

        if (EnabledTurnoverClassifications == null)
        {
            EnabledTurnoverClassifications = new List<TurnoverClassification>();
        }

        if (Customers == null)
        {
            Customers = new List<Customer>();
        }
    }
```

The model

```
class TurnoverClassification
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RebateBase> RebateBasesAvailable{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RebateBase> RebateBasesEnabled{ get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int NumericalValue { get; set; }
}
```